# Question about Postgres/Redshift date formatting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

One of the data sources we have coming into our Redshift, is MySQL and all the date formatting is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. When querying, this gives me a bunch of issue, especially when I have to make reoccurring reporting for it etc. I tried converting it to 'YYYY/MM/DD', but it complicates it especially when altering the date (timezone, trunc). Currently to cover reoccurring reporting I found TRUNC(timestamp) = DATE(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())). I was hoping there was a better way to deal with this and this format of dates. I know this is an ambiguous question, but ultimately I am looking for a better way to handle this date formatting.

Comment: That is the `ISO` format so I am not sure how that could be a problem? Can you provide an exact example of the issue(s) you are having?

Comment: It may be a back end issue, but whenever I to alter the time zone, it does not work. Additionally, the only way I found that is effective to do the previous day is TRUNC(timestamp) = DATE(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), when YYYY/MM/DD never has this issue. To be clear the only difference is the - instead of /

Comment: Without an example with actual values and resultant error output, this is going to be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Preferably, dates are stored in Date or Timestamp fields. The internal structure used for the date is completely separate to the `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY/MM/DD` strings you see, which are typically created by the SQL client you are using. As long as the dates are correctly stored as dates rather than strings, all date functions should work correctly. What is your _actual_ requirement? Are you wanting to query up to yesterday's date? Does the field contain a timestamp, or just a date?

Comment: As per comments above, what is the actual data type of the column? If its a date or timestamp data type then the date is stored as an internal representation and how you see it in your sql results is just a factor of how the sql client tool presents it. However if the data type is a string/varchar then you might be having string to date conversions issues. Basically you need to include more information about the schema and data involved and an actual example of the problem before anyone can give a meaningful answer.